# Is there any way to find out what uses a strategic resource?

Tags: stellaris

One of my strategic resources shows 0/1. Is there any way of finding out which building/module is using that resource, without manually going over each of my non-sectored planets and each of my spaceports?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of influence to spare, you can always try sectoring the resource and using the "missing a resource" notification to find the object that was originally using it...